# Fast split excel file by value in c#

Tags: c#, excel, split

I need to split excel file by selected row. I have quite big amount of row so split by hand took too much time.

```
 worksheet.Range["A1"].EntireRow.Copy();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook nowy = excel.Workbooks.Add();
                Excel.Worksheet sh = nowy.Sheets.Add();
                sh.Name = "test";

                Excel.Range r = sh.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow;
                r.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
                int y;
                int limit=range.Rows.Count;
                for ( y= 2; y <= limit; y++)
                {
                   ile++;
                   worksheet.Range["A" + y].EntireRow.Copy();
                   Trace.Write(ile + ",");
                   r = sh.get_Range("A2", "A2").EntireRow;
                   r.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);

                    if (worksheet.Cells[y, x].value != worksheet.Cells[y+1, x].value)
                    {
                        osredu=worksheet.Cells[y, x].value;
                        string plik_ = "c:\\plikixml_dzielone\\" + osredu;
                        nowy.SaveAs(plik_,
                            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                            false,
                            false,
                            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared,
                            false,
                            false,
                            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                            System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
                        nowy.Close();
                        worksheet.Range["A1"].EntireRow.Copy();
                        nowy = excel.Workbooks.Add();
                        sh = nowy.Sheets.Add();
                        sh.Name = "test";
                        r = sh.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow;
                        r.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
                        Trace.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                        Trace.WriteLine(ile_szkol+ "---"+ osredu + " : " + ile);
                        Trace.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                        ile = 0;
                        ile_szkol++;
                    }

                }
```

I mate this code. It works fine but is extremly slow and lock clipboard from using. Split over 9500 rows took one hour. Do You have any idea how improve speed of this code?

Comment: How about copying the whole file N times first, then deleting the rows you don't want in each file?

Comment: Still tooks too much time, I will have 241 files

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why are you storing all the data in 1 spreadsheet when it seems you really want it split down by some criteria?

Comment: This is not my file. I just get it to split.

Comment: What version of excel are you working on? Use OpenXML or even ClosedXML API's. It will be much faster than the Interop services...http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Showcase&referringTitle=Home

Comment: I use excel 2013, file is in 2007

Answer (score 0):

Try using OleDb driver for this task. It should be faster then automation.

```
string sourceConnectionString =
             @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 XML;Data Source=C:\source\MyExcel.xlsx;";

using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{       
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This a connection to an excel file, how is it solvin the problem?

Comment: OP needs to process a bunch of files, and automation is not way to go in this case, that is why i suggest to use oledb for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure saving o(n) times and doing worksheet.Range["A1"].EntireRow.Copy(); every time is not necessary. Can't really see what's what with some of those variable names.

However using [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can figure out yourself what's taking so long.